# How can I make the hostages come with me on the chopper?

Tags: the-expendabros

In *The Expendabros*, you can revive and arm some hostages. They fight for you and come with you, but when the helicopter comes to pick you up, they don't jump onto the rope ladder with you.
They are tallied among the dead in the level score, and they are the last of the dead, which seems to mean that they died last, while you flew away in the helicopter.

Is there any way to save them by taking them with me?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "save" the hostages to my knowledge, you can recruit them and have them fight with you but they won't jump onto the helicopter at the end. I am honestly surprised you got them to the helicopter they usually die in a second when I play.